# Multiple words in entities with LUIS

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I would like to know if there is any way to make LUIS capable of recognizing entities formed by multiple words in a flexible way.

I know that if I select multiple words LUIS will recognize them this but what if I have longer entities?

For example suppose we have some products in a database, one of them is formed by 4 words like: `Abc summer green jacket`. Now I type my intent "add abc summer black jacket to shopping cart", do I have to create an utterance with entity "product" formed by 4 jackets?

What if one day my database gets a product formed by 10 words? Should I try other solutions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `Abc summer green jacket`, a super-simple method might be assigning `"Abc"`, `"summer"`, and `"green"` to a single adjective entity. We would then place the product, `"jacket"` in another entity for products, and then lump the two of them together in a [composite entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/add-entities#custom-entities).

Our composite entity would at least have these two children entities, say "Adjectives" and "Clothing", and we'll label the composite entity "Product".

> *"add abc summer black jacket to shopping cart"*

If we use this as our training utterance, we'll start by wrapping `"abc summer black jacket"` into out composite entity by clicking on `"abc"` and then "Wrap in Composite Entity". Select "Product" and to finish the label we'll select `"jacket"`. Inside you'll need to label the three adjectives with the "Adjectives" entity, and then in the future (though perhaps with more training) your model should be able to recognize multiple of the same type of entity inside your composite entity.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same. Microsoft have made is super simple. Please follow instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-how-to-add-example-utterances).

In a nutshell, add utterance, click start of entity and then click at the end of entity   square brackets will appear around multiple words. Mark it as entity.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like a standard "multi-select".  On Windows, hold Ctrl and click or select each word in the phrase.